# EntityManager createNativeQuery returning wrong result set in Java Springboot

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot

I am stuck in this for half a day. My question may be scary with the image and JSon but my problem is not that difficult. I think I  included all the information need for one to help.  I have the following query

```
select id, preco, 'casas-venda' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from casa_venda
 union
select id, preco, 'apartamentos-vendas' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from apartamento_venda  
 union

select id, preco, 'loft-vendas' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from loft_venda

 union

select id, preco, 'studio-vendas' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from studio_venda

 union
 select id, preco, 'quitinete-venda' as link, descricao, dir, slug from quitinete_venda
```

This query when run throught PgAdmin 4 returns this

[image]

But the JSon that I receive is this

I forgot to tell how I noticed the JSon is wrong. I should have a "link" with "studio-venda" and "link" with "loft-venda".

```
[{"id":5,"preco":190000,"descricao":"Apartamento bem confortável","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-4-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"29","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":10,"preco":667000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bonito","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-1-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"33","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg"]},{"id":4,"preco":190000,"descricao":"Apartamento bem confortável","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-4-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"28","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.olx.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":6,"preco":91000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bonito","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-1-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"30","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg"]},{"id":2,"preco":90000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bom","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-4-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"26","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":3,"preco":90000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bom","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-4-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"27","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":2,"preco":90000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bom","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-4-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"26","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-4-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":9,"preco":667000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bonito","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-1-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"34","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg"]},{"id":1,"preco":1350,"descricao":"Apartamento super","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-2-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"25","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":1,"preco":1350,"descricao":"Apartamento super","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-2-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"25","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":7,"preco":91000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bonito","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-1-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"31","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.exemplo.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg"]},{"id":8,"preco":91000,"descricao":"Apartamento muito bonito","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-1-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"32","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.olx.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","casa-venda-1-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg"]},{"id":1,"preco":1350,"descricao":"Apartamento super","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-2-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"25","imagemPrincipal":"https://img.olx.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":1,"preco":1350,"descricao":"Apartamento super","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-2-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"25","imagemPrincipal":"https://example.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]},{"id":1,"preco":1350,"descricao":"Apartamento super","link":"apartamentos-vendas","slug":"casa-venda-2-dormitorios-Franca-São Paulo","dir":"25","imagemPrincipal":"https://example.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg","miniaturasImagens":["casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_2.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_3.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_5.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_7.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_4.jpg","temp.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_1.jpg","casa-venda-2-dormitorios-franca-sao-paulo_6.jpg"]}]
```

Here is my Java code

```
String q = "select id, preco, 'casas-venda' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from casa_venda " +
"union all\n" +
"select id, preco, 'apartamentos-vendas' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from apartamento_venda  "
                       + "union all\n"

+ "select id, preco, 'loft-vendas' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from loft_venda  "

                       + "union all\n"

       + "select id, preco, 'studio-vendas' as link,   descricao, dir, slug from studio_venda  "

                       + "union all\n"

                       + "select id, preco, 'quitinete-venda' as link, descricao, dir, slug from quitinete_venda";

               List<Imovel> imoveis = entityManager.createNativeQuery(q, Imovel.class)

                       .getResultList();
```

Bellow is Imovel class

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "imovelMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = Imovel.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "preco", type = Integer.class),

                    @ColumnResult(name = "descricao", type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "link", type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "slug", type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "dir", type = String.class)

                }))
public class Imovel {

    public Imovel() {

    }

    public Imovel(Integer id, Integer preco, String descricao, String link, String slug, String dir) {
        this.id = id;
        this.preco = preco;
        this.descricao = descricao;
         this.link = link;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.dir = dir;

        System.out.println(this.getPreco());
        System.out.println("/var/www/back_imoveis/back_imoveis/imoveis/src/main/resources/fotos/" + this.dir + "/miniaturas");

        File folder = new File("/var/www/back_imoveis/back_imoveis/imoveis/src/main/resources/fotos/" + this.dir + "/miniaturas");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                miniaturasImagens.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }

        this.miniaturasImagens = miniaturasImagens;

    }

    public Imovel(Integer preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "preco")
    private Integer preco;

    @Column(name = "descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "link")
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "slug")
    private String slug;

    @Column(name = "dir")
    private String dir;

    @Transient
    private String imagemPrincipal;

    @Transient
    private List<String> miniaturasImagens = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Integer getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(Integer preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImagemPrincipal() {

        return "https://img.olx.com.br/images/07/07592902iiiiii8267077.jpg";
        // return imagemPrincipal;
    }

    public void setImagemPrincipal(String imagemPrincipal) {
        this.imagemPrincipal = imagemPrincipal;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getDir() {
        return dir;
    }

    public void setDir(String dir) {
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public List<String> getMiniaturasImagens() {

        return miniaturasImagens;
    }

    public void setMiniaturasImagens(List<String> imagens) {

        this.miniaturasImagens = imagens;

    }

}
```

Comment: You do not have `link` argument and you do not set this field in this constructor: `public Imovel(Integer id, Integer preco, String descricao, String slug, String dir)`

Comment: I correct that, I am stil getting weird results.

Comment: I think I am in the right track now. I guess  the query is wielding weird results because of the values in the table, specially for nulls. I performed a union between only two tables and get wrong result, I noticed null  in a table and the other no nulls, I removed the nulls of the table I now it produced results more consistently. I am new to Java, in the new technologies I always think that bugs are due to some limitation of the techonology itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very fraightened by the bug I was having, because createNativeQuery was like a light in the end of the tunnel after struggling with the limitations of JpaRepository. After getting rid of nulls on the database column now the results are pretty much what I expect. I don't know why my union with nulls running directly on the database  works and with createNativeQuery it produces strange results. The particular column I was having problem is "descricao", some table had null some have characters. I hope it can help others!